# Feature selection using mixed data types

Tags: python, feature-selection

I am trying to create some code that gives weight to the most impactful features.

My dataframe contains both nominal and categorical data.

example data:

```
[Brand]      [Model]       [Car_price]      [...]       [Prime]  
BMW           X1            40,000                       300
```

The Y is the prime and X is all other columns.

I tried using the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
df = pd.read_csv(data, delimiter=";")
#df = df.dropna(axis=1)
array = df.values
X = array[:,(6,7,9,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,27,34,35,37,44,45,47,48,54,61,62)]

Y = array[:,51]

forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1, class_weight='balanced', max_depth=5)
forest.fit(X, Y)
```

And get the following error: ValueError: could not convert string to float

I know there is a way to transform from string into numerical data, but was wondering if it is necessary. What fixes can I apply to get weighted features?

Comment: Please, give an example of your input data you are reading with pandas

Comment: @AndreaBarnabò added